# Linear transformation of a circle

Tags: linear-algebra

We are given:

> $T:R^2 \rightarrow R^2$ by $T(x_1,x_2)=(5x_1+2x_2, 3x_1-x_2)$.
>
> For $S = \{(x_1,x_2): \ (x_1-1)^2+(x_2-2)^2=\frac{1}{2}\ \}$

I did the transformation under $T$ and got the following: $$(5x_1+2x_2-1)^2+(3x_1-x_2-2)^2=\frac{1}{2} $$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

No, a little more work is needed.  $T$ is not a substitution of variables, it is a mapping of points in the plane to other points.  Your set $S$ is a curve in the plane and we want to know the new shape of the curve after we apply $T$ to each of the points in $S$.

Notice that the associated matrix of $T$ is $$ A = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 5 & 2 \\ 3 & -1 \end{array} \right].$$

Since it is a nonsingular linear transformation (determinant $\neq 0$), $T$ can only stretch and rotate the plane.  $S$ is a circle centered at $(1,2)$ with radius $1/\sqrt{2}$ so let's parametrize it by $\theta$: $$S = \left\{ \left(1 + {1\over \sqrt{2}}\cos(\theta),2+{1\over \sqrt{2}}\sin(\theta)\right) : 0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi \right\}.$$
Then the image of $S$ under $T$ is the set of points 
$$ \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 5 & 2 \\ 3 & -1 \end{array} \right] \cdot \left[ \begin{array}{c} 1 + {1\over \sqrt{2}}\cos(\theta) \\ 2+{1\over \sqrt{2}}\sin(\theta) \end{array} \right] = 
\left[ \begin{array}{c} 9 + {1\over \sqrt{2}}(5\cos(\theta)+2\sin(\theta)) \\ 1+{1\over \sqrt{2}}(3\cos(\theta) - \sin(\theta)) \end{array} \right].$$
This is an ellipse, centered at $(9,1)$.  I'll leave working out the length and direction of the major and minor axes to you - you might find it simplest to plug in some nice values of $\theta$ and plot a few points on the image $T(S)$.